# Inserting CSV into MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I know that there are loads of questions related to this however I can't seem to find a solution for my errors.

My CSV :

[image: My CSV]

My SQL Table :

[image]

I would like to insert the CSV in MYSQL.

I understand that I do not need to code for this however, I would like the data to be in MYSQL as the python codes to retrieve codes refreshes every 1 hour.

Here are my codes :

**First Try** :

```
<?php

//database connection details
$connect = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','admin','password');

if (!$connect) {
 die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

//your database name
$cid =mysql_select_db('weather',$connect);

// path where your CSV file is located
define('CSV_PATH','C:/scripts/');

// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "nea.csv"; 


if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   fgetcsv($handle);   
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
      $col[$c] = $data[$c];
    }

// column name in mysql = column in csv?
 $validTime = $col[0];
 $Date = $col[1];
 $Time = $col[2];
 $Lat = $col[3];
 $Lon = $col[4];
 $AreaName = $col[5];

// SQL Query to insert data into DataBase
$query = "INSERT INTO neaweather(validTime, Date, Time, Lat, Lon, AreaName)   
VALUES('".$col[0]."','".$col[1]."','".$col[2]."','".$col[3]."','".$col[4]."','".$col[5]."')";
$s = mysql_query($query, $connect );
 }
  fclose($handle);
 }

echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

**Second Try :**

```
<?php
//set the connection variables
$hostname = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "admin";
$password = "password";
$database = "weather";
$filename = "C:/scripts/nea.csv";

//connect to mysql database
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or    
    die("Error " . mysqli_error($myConnection));

// open the csv file
$fp = fopen($filename,"r");

//parse the csv file row by row
 while(($row = fgetcsv($fp,"500",",")) != FALSE)
 {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO neaweather (ValidTime, Date, Time, Lat, Lon, AreaName) VALUES ( '".mysqli_escape_string($data[0])."','".mysqli_escape_string($data[1])."','".mysqli_escape_string($data[2])."','".mysqli_escape_string($data[3])."','".mysqli_escape_string($data[4])."','".mysqli_escape_string($data[5])."')";
    mysqli_query($myConnection,$sql);
    if($query){
        echo "row inserted\n";
    }
    else{
        echo die(mysqli_error());
    }
}
fclose($fp);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($myConnection);
?>
```

**EDIT**: I ran both codes and there's no error at all. However, data is still not entering MYSQL

Comment: `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' <using password : NO >` means you are not sending any credentials to mysql hence connection  was not established. This would be because you got the connection as `$connection` but tried using `$myConnection` later in the code

Comment: What do you mean by I am not sending credentials to mysql ? :x

Comment: You need to give the correct login/password to MySQL

Comment: Its correct as I have other php codes which is meant to insert data into MYSQL too

Comment: Even if the connection succeeds, the insert will fail because `$data` is not defined though `$row` is

Comment: How can i define $data?

Comment: @plzhelpmi It can't be correct, you specify an user and a password at the top of your file, yet you get `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' <using password : NO >`, so your connection is not using your specified credentials

Comment: I mean your are mixing `mysqli_*` functions with `mysql_*` functions, causing to open a second connection with no creds (look at your insert SQL)

Comment: How do I know which one to use may i ask?

Comment: You need to use `mysqli_query` as you are connecting with `mysqli_connect` (other than that every `mysql_* function` is deprecated)

Comment: Read the documentation: [Choosing a MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php#mysqlinfo.api.choosing)

Comment: I have edited my question! @DarkBee

Comment: The error messages are very clear about what the problems are.

Comment: What does "Undefined variable" means? As it is pointing to : $sql = "INSERT INTO neaweather (ValidTime, Date, Time, Lat, Lon, AreaName) VALUES ( '".mysql_escape_string($data[0])."','".mysql_escape_string($data[1])."','".mysql_escape_string($data[2])."','".mysql_escape_string($data[3])."','".mysql_escape_string($data[4])."','".mysql_escape_string($data[5])."')";

Comment: Undefined means undefined, the variable was never set/initialised... You should be using `$row`, not `$data`, don't just c/p code from the internet and expect it to run

Comment: Ohh, haha my bad. Also, " PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given" i receive this error and went to google and added a SQL statement to it : "$query = mysqli_query($sql,"SELECT * FROM neaweather");" however, i got another error saying : " PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given" I dont really get it

Comment: The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/) contains the syntax for all PHP functions, with plenty of examples. You should use it **everytime** you have a problem with PHP code.

Comment: Hi, I solved all the errors but data is still not entering MYSQL :/

Answer (score -2):

I would like to suggest if you use this library, It supports csv,xls,xlsx files import and export.

I have used this several times and it works like charm.

**PHPExcel:** https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. But my codes dont have an error now however, its not working and Im not sure why. Would you be able to help?

Comment: Hi, I left you a message on skype :)

Comment: Sure, i'm on skype, plz get back to messages on skype, i will debug and correct the code and repost here after that,

Comment: Working sample code with db schema and csv file can be downloaded from this link: 

http://www.filedropper.com/workingsample

It's working fine.